# Hpricot version not working

Tags: ruby, jekyll, hpricot

I'm trying to migrate my blog to Jekyll, following these instructions: http://jekyllrb.com/docs/migrations/

I've got all my posts in .xml format, but the command to convert them does not seem to be working:

```
    ruby -rubygems -e 'require "jekyll/jekyll-import/wordpressdotcom";
    JekyllImport::WordpressDotCom.process({ :source => "wordpress.xml" })'
/home/robin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- hpricot (LoadError)
    from /home/robin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /home/robin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/jekyll-import-0.1.0.beta3/lib/jekyll/jekyll-import/wordpressdotcom.rb:4:in `'
    from /home/robin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
    from /home/robin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
    from /home/robin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `'
```

I guess this is because Hpricot is not installed (`gem list` does not show it, even after I installed it with gem install). It could also be a Ruby version issue (hence the multiple "from" lines `ruby -v` tells me it's ruby 1.9.3p448 .

Many thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GitHub page for Hpricot says:

> Hpricot has ended. Please consider an alternative like nokogiri.

Hpricot has not been maintained for a long time (see GitHub page) - you should change your XML parser to either Nokogiri or Ox:

- [Ox](https://github.com/ohler55/ox)
- [Nokogiri](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri)